How do I access the second (or Nth) entry that matches the script's criteria?
There is a script
#IfWinActive, ahk_class illustrator
    RWin::Send, !frf

The menu commands looks like this
...
exportDocs
fitAndCenter
fitSelection
fitAndScale
...

Cuurently the script selects fitAndCenter entry. How to access the second f* entry, i.e. fitSelection?
(What about the Nth entry?)

Normally, for menu shortcuts not defined by the software, Windows indexes them by the initial letter. If that letter is already 'taken,' it uses the next available letter, and so on. But to know if it is defined by the software or not, you can only test it. Try the following:
#IfWinActive, ahk_class illustrator
    RWin::Send, !irf

Basically, the menu you posted would have the shortcuts like this:
...
exportDocs
'f'itAndCenter
f'i'tSelection
fi't'AndScale
...

